# Find all integers $x$ such that $x ^{86}\equiv 6\pmod{29}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find all integers $x$ such that $x ^{86}\equiv 6\pmod{29}$

---

By Fermat’s Little Theorem

$x ^{28}\equiv 1\pmod{29}$

I am stuck from here any idea?

Comment: Hint: what is $x^{(84)} \pmod{29}?$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am continue from end of your attempt.

By Fermat’s Little Theorem,

$$x^{28}\equiv 1 \pmod{29}$$

Thus,
$$x^{86}\equiv x^2\pmod{29}$$

So, we only need to solve

$$x^{2}\equiv 6\pmod{29}$$

This is the same as

$$x^{2}\equiv 64\pmod{29}$$

which means that
$$x^{2}-64\equiv (x − 8)(x + 8)\equiv 0 \pmod{29}$$

Thus,
$$x\equiv 8\pmod{29}$$
$$x\equiv 21\pmod{29}$$

Are the solution's

Comment: Alternatively $$2^5\equiv3\pmod{29}\implies2\cdot3\equiv2^{1+5}$$

Answer (score 1):

Fermat's Little Theorem gives $x^{28}\equiv 1\mod 29$ and therefore $1\equiv x^{3(28)}\equiv x^{84}$. Thus the congruence $x^{86}\equiv 6\mod29$ is equivalent to the congruence $x^2\equiv 6\mod29$ whose solution set is the union of the residue classes $8+29\Bbb Z$ and $-8+29\Bbb Z$.